# What is the character limit on an Esri subtype description?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, subtype

I cannot find this documentation anywhere. Essentially want to know if too long of a subtype description can cause errors.

Comment: Did you find any documentation on subtypes?  If so I think you should link to what you have reviewed at the beginning of your question.  Have you performed any quick tests using a long description?

Comment: I left this open for a couple of days just in case anyone had an answer available off the top of their head.  However, I am now voting to close it because our focussed Q&A format is for problems you actually face, whereas here you are merely trying to pre-empt a problem you might possibly face, which is one that you can very easily test to determine whether it appears to be an actual problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is something that you can very easily test to determine whether an actual problem might exist.